# How to use external Tomcat server in Netbeans on Linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat6, netbeans-7

I am trying to use the external tomcat server installed on my machine (Ubuntu 11.10) and I a going through the motions of adding a new server to Netbeans, in the Server Location field I enter the `/usr/share/tomcat6` directory but it gives an error:

```
The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid
```

I have searched Google, used the Netbeans wiki, and have searched here also but nothing seems to be able to get me past this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Netbeans does support external Tomcat installations.  It does so without any problems on Windows, but there are a few wrinkles if you want to do it on Linux - with Ubuntu-based distributions anyway.

I wrote up my experiences here:

http://www.peredur.net/2011/12/linux-tomcat-and-netbeans/

Hopefully, that should help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to debug a remote Tomcat, see http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q3.